# how do i use mysql connector with godady account?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, mysql-connector

I've been using the MySQL connector assembly to use mysql with asp. everything works fine on the testing server here at home, but when I upload the site to my godaddy account, i get the following error:

```
Line 11:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
Line 12:       <assemblies>
Line 13:         <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
Line 14:         <add assembly="MySql.Data.Entity, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
Line 15:         <add assembly="MySql.Web, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
```

Line 13 is highlighted in red. I'm assuming this is a problem because the application can't find the dll on the remote server. I'm kind of new at this. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet forums are so dirty. So hard to find a straight answer on anything. In the middle of a pile of posts, I was able to find a simple answer:

Upload the 3 assembly files to the /bin folder on your hosting account:

1. MySql.Data.dll
2. MySql.Data.Entity.dll
3. MySql.Web.dll

Thats it!

now my only issue is that visual studio keeps deleting those dlls when I publish site updates :S

Comment: I'm having the same issue(mysql connector to work on godaddy). I copied these three files over and I get the following error: "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed."

Comment: make sure they're set to copy to the output directory when you build